# Shopping cart poblem sorting shopping cart

Tags: php, laravel

I have controller

```
public function category(Categories $category)
{
    $product_random = DB::table('products')->where('is_active', 1);
    $currency = DB::table('currency')->where('id', 1)->get();
    if(count($category->children))
    {
        $categories = Categories::where('parent_id', $category->id)->get();
        return view('catalog2', compact('category', 'categories', 'product_random', 'currency', 'category_id'));
    }
    else
    {
        $categories = Categories::where('parent_id', null)->get();
        $categories_pod = Categories::where('parent_id', $category->id)->get();
        $product_s = Product::where('is_active', 1)->get();
        $product = product::where('category_id', $category->id)->where('is_active', 1)->get();
        if($price = request('individualprice'))
        {
            $product->orderBy('individualprice', $price);
        }
        return view('products', compact('category', 'product', 'categories', 'currency', 'product_s','categories_pod'));
    }
}
```

and BLADE

```
<div><a href="?price=desc">Sort by price descending</a></div>
<div><a href="?price=asc">Sort by price</a></div>
```

Comment: You're passing `price` in the Url, but checking for `individualprice` in the request.

Comment: @aynber this individualprice my price in database

Comment: `request('individualprice')`. That would not exist in the request, as you're passing `price` in the get variable, instead. Change that to price, and it should work as you expect

Comment: price? I get error Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist.

Comment: Because `$product` is a collection, and no longer part of the query builder. Use [sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sortby) instead. You may need to change it to check for the value of `price` and use `sortByDesc`.

Comment: arsort() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given

Comment: Looking at the definition for sortBy : `sortBy($callback, $options = SORT_REGULAR, $descending = false)`. It doesn't allow for ASC/DESC like orderBy does. Check for the value of `price`, and use `sortBy`/`sortByDesc` as needed.

Comment: if($price = request('price')){ $product->sortBy('price', $price);} and blade <a href="?price=sortByDesc">Sort by price descending</a></div>                                <div><a href="?price=sortBy">Sort by price</a></div>

Comment: No. `if(request('price') == 'asc') { $product->sortBy('individualprice'); } else if(request('price') == 'desc') { $product->sortByDesc('individualprice'); }`. should work

Comment: it is not work.